# python SSL error c:1000 using boto3 to connect to AWS

Tags: python, boto3, aws-glue

Having an issue with python script (3.12) that previously worked that used boto3 to connect to AWS Glue and return table information.

The error message is:

"botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://glue.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)"

I use a separate script to first authenticate with AWS and then running code such as:

```
import boto3
import json
import datetime
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
next_token = ""
client = boto3.client('glue', region_name ='us-west-2')
crawler_tables = []
 
while True:
    response = client.get_tables(DatabaseName = 'XXXX', NextToken = next_token)
    #print(response)
    def myconverter(o):
        if isinstance(o,datetime.datetime):
            return o.__str__()
 
    print(json.dumps(response, default=myconverter))
    for tables in response['TableList']:
        for columns in tables['StorageDescriptor']['Columns']:
            crawler_tables.append(tables['Name'] + '|' + columns['Name']+ '|' + columns['Type'])
    next_token = response.get('NextToken')
    if next_token is None:
        break
print(crawler_tables)
```

The error is new as the script functioned 8-12 months ago and believe that some security/network or workstation permissions have changed but not able to find the root cause.

I have tried to install certificates using the github Gist install Cerfificates.command But get the error:
OSError: [WinError 1314] A required privilege is not held by the client: '..\.venv\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem' -> 'cert.pem'

I've checked the security on the folders and appears I should have the access needed (windows 10).

If this error and the above SSLError are actually tied together I've looked at options for moving the location of certs default directory c:\program files\common files\SSL\certs to some location I have full permissions to but not sure if going down the right path to resolve.

I appreciate input!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my python script that pulled metadata about AWS glue tables working by combining the different cert files together.  I'm sure there are repercussions for my resolution but will continue testing.